# Advice on multi-output regression task: Forecasting Refugee Flows

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, forecasting, predictive-models, graph-neural-network

I have a question on possible approaches in modeling and predicting refugee flows.

**Task**

My task is to predict the number of refugees for a country origin-destination pair for a given year. For example, given data up to 2016, we have to predict the number of refugees that arrived in Colombia from Venezuela in 2017.

**Data Summary**

Aside from historical refugee flows, we are also collecting data on:

- historical migration data
- LDA topic modeled newspaper text
- indices related to conflict and fragility
- historical google trends data of relevant search terms (ex. people in Venezuela searching for 'passport' or 'Colombia')
- socioeconomic stats about countries.

Note that we have both country-specific data (e.x. the historical level of conflict), but also country pair-specific data that can either be directed (e.x. people in Venezuela searching for 'Colombia') or undirected (e.x. whether or not countries share a common language)

**How to model this/shape the data?**

One of the main challenges is that the data can be shaped multiple ways, including:

- ***Pair forecasting***- What is the number of people going from Syria to Turkey in 2015?

  - The output is a scalar value denoting the number of people from the origin country to destination country at time t.
  - The input is origin country characteristics, destination country characteristics, and characteristics specific to the origin-destination pair/relationship.
  - This is the approach that seems to be common in the literature- predicting each origin-destination pair individually.
  - An implicit assumption in this approach is that each corridor's refugee traffic is independent of other corridors. For example, knowing information about the increased traffic on google of people in Venezuela searching for 'Peru' isn't relevant in predicting the amount of people traveling from Venezuela to Colombia.
- ***Single origin, multi-destination forecasting***- What is the number of people leaving South Sudan in 2016 and where are they all going?

  - The output is a vectory representing the number of people from the origin country  arriving to each destination country at time t.
  - The input is origin country characteristics, characteristics of all destination countries, and characteristics specific to each origin-destination pair/relationship.
  - This is the approach that makes sense to me, as I think destination is secondary to one's desire to get out of a dangerous place.
  - I have thought about this as a 2 stage model though it doesn't have to be- first predicting simply the total number of refugees leaving a country, and then allocating them to different destination countries.

Another consideration is that we are dealing with mixed frequency data- while our y variable is yearly, some of our X's (e.g. google trends) are monthly. This could be aggregated to avoid complexity, but there would be a loss of information.

I will try a RandomForest pair-forecasting approach as a baseline, but I am also very interested in modeling the data the second way, where origin country characteristics, characteristics of all destination countries, and characteristics specific to each origin-destination pair/relationship are used to predict the total volume of people and where they are going to go.

The challenge is that common regression models aren't designed for this. How would one design a model where country pair-specific data both informs the total origin-country outflow and informs the pair-specific forecast?

I think modeling the data like this would either require using Graph Neural Networks or designing a neural network architecture specific to this challenge, but I am unsure where to start.

Any advice or places to start are greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an interesting problem (which I'm sure you've made progress on since your post).

Once suggestion would be to think about using a Hidden Markov model in a paired forecasting approach. This might align you more with the literature while alleviating your concern

*An implicit assumption in this approach is that each corridor's refugee traffic is independent of other corridors. For example, knowing information about the increased traffic on google of people in Venezuela searching for 'Peru' isn't relevant in predicting the amount of people traveling from Venezuela to Colombia.*

An HMM approach would allow for a simple Markov Process framework while including "interdependence."